# “Requested registry access is not allowed” in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I have a requirement to read registry values in **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**. But when I am trying to get the subkey object with read access, I get this exception: "**Requested registry access is not allowed**". ( *Note :: In my app i am not doing any write or modifications to registry.*)

This error only occurs when I try running from client machine. In my machine, it works well. **Since both the machines have administrative access**, I think some other thing is causing the problem. I am able to read and edit registry values manually from the client machine.

I have edited manifest file and changed required permissions from asInvoker to requireAdministrator. But no luck. Any workarounds?

Here is my code sample.

```
public List<SysApps> GetAllApps()
{
    List<SysApps> appList = new List<SysApps>();

    // The area's we are scanning
    appList.AddRange(this.LoadFiles(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry32,
        @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
    appList.AddRange(this.LoadFiles(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32,
        @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
    appList.AddRange(this.LoadFiles(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64,
        @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));

    return appList.OrderBy(r => r.DisplayName).ToList();
}

private List<SysApps> LoadFiles(RegistryHive reghive, RegistryView regview, string regkeypath)
{
    ist<SysApps> appList = new List<SysApps>();

    using (RegistryKey regedit = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(reghive, regview))
    using (RegistryKey regkey = regedit.OpenSubKey(regkeypath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree))
    {
        if (regkey == null) goto last;

        foreach (string subkey in regkey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            if (subkey == null) continue;

            using (RegistryKey key = regkey.OpenSubKey(subkey))
            {
                if (key == null) continue;

                    SysApps sysapp = new SysApps();

                    sysapp._displayName = key.GetValue("DisplayName") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("DisplayName");
                    sysapp._publisher = key.GetValue("Publisher") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("Publisher");
                    sysapp._installDate = key.GetValue("InstallDate") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("InstallDate");

                    var decValue = key.GetValue("EstimatedSize") == null ? "0" : key.GetValue("EstimatedSize");
                    sysapp._estimatedSize = decValue.ToString() == "0" ? string.Empty : AppCommon.GetSize(decValue.ToString());

                    sysapp._displayIcon = key.GetValue("DisplayIcon") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("DisplayIcon");

                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sysapp._displayIcon) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(sysapp._displayName))
                        sysapp._displayIcon = this.GetIconForRoot(sysapp._displayName);


                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sysapp._displayIcon))
                        sysapp._displayIcon = sysapp._displayIcon.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();

                    sysapp._displayVersion = key.GetValue("DisplayVersion") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
                    sysapp._uninstallString = key.GetValue("UninstallString") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("UninstallString");
                    sysapp._modifyPath = key.GetValue("ModifyPath") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("ModifyPath");

                    // Validate
                    var rType = (string)key.GetValue("ReleaseType");
                    var sComponent = key.GetValue("SystemComponent");
                    var pName = (string)key.GetValue("ParentDisplayName");

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sysapp._displayName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(rType) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pName) && (sComponent == null))
                    {
                        AppCommon.FileSize += Int32.Parse(decValue.ToString());
                        appList.Add(sysapp);
                    }

                    key.Flush();
                    key.Close();
                }
            }

            regkey.Flush();
            regkey.Close();
        }

    last:
        return appList;
}

private string GetIconForRoot(string productName)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    string installerKey = @"Installer\Products";

    bool isFound = false;

    using (RegistryKey regedit = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, RegistryView.Registry32))
    using (RegistryKey regkey = regedit.OpenSubKey(installerKey, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree))
    {
        if (regkey == null) goto last;

        foreach (string subkey in regkey.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            if (subkey == null) continue;

            using (RegistryKey key = regkey.OpenSubKey(subkey))
            {
                if (key.GetValue("ProductName") != null)
                    if (productName == key.GetValue("ProductName").ToString())
                        if (key.GetValue("ProductIcon") != null)
                        {
                            isFound = true;
                            result = key.GetValue("ProductIcon").ToString();
                        }

                    key.Flush();
                    key.Close();

                    if (isFound) break;
            }
        }

        egkey.Flush();
        regkey.Close();
    }

    last:
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code where you are trying to read registry value.

Comment: I added the code sample.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Finally I found the answer. I did following changes to my code.

```
public async Task<List<Apps>> GetAllApps()
{
    List<Apps> _installedApps = new List<Apps>();

    _installedApps.AddRange(await this.LoadFiles(Registry.CurrentUser,
                    @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
    _installedApps.AddRange(await this.LoadFiles(Registry.LocalMachine,
                    @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));
    _installedApps.AddRange(await this.LoadFiles(Registry.LocalMachine,
                    @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"));

    return _installedApps.OrderBy(x => x.DisplayName).ToList();
}

private async Task<List<Apps>> LoadFiles(RegistryKey rkey, string regkeypath)
        {
            List<Apps> appList = new List<Apps>();

            RegistryKey regkey = 
                rkey.OpenSubKey(regkeypath, 
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree, 
                RegistryRights.ReadKey);

            if (regkey == null) goto last;

            foreach (string subkey in regkey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (subkey == null) continue;

                using (RegistryKey key = regkey.OpenSubKey(subkey))
                {
                    if (key == null) continue;

                    // Validating
                    var rType = (string)key.GetValue("ReleaseType");
                    var sComponent = key.GetValue("SystemComponent");
                    var pName = (string)key.GetValue("ParentDisplayName");
                    var dName = (string)key.GetValue("DisplayName");

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dName) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(rType) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(pName) && (sComponent == null))
                        appList.Add(await ReadKeyValues(key));

                    key.Flush();
                    key.Close();
                }
            }

            regkey.Flush();
            regkey.Close();

        last:
            return appList;
        }
        private Task<string> GetIconForRoot(string productName)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;
            string installerKey = @"Installer\Products";

            bool isFound = false;

            RegistryKey regkey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(installerKey, 
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree, 
                RegistryRights.ReadKey);

            if (regkey == null) goto last;

            foreach (string subkey in regkey.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                if (subkey == null) continue;

                using (RegistryKey key = regkey.OpenSubKey(subkey))
                {
                    if (key.GetValue("ProductName") != null)
                        if (productName == key.GetValue("ProductName").ToString())
                            if (key.GetValue("ProductIcon") != null)
                            {
                                isFound = true;
                                result = key.GetValue("ProductIcon").ToString();
                            }
                    key.Flush();
                    key.Close();

                    if (isFound) break;
                }
            }

            regkey.Flush();
            regkey.Close();

        last:
            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
        private async Task<Apps> ReadKeyValues(RegistryKey key)
        {
            Apps installedApp = new Apps();

            installedApp._displayName = key.GetValue("DisplayName") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("DisplayName");
            installedApp._publisher = key.GetValue("Publisher") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("Publisher");
            installedApp._installDate = key.GetValue("InstallDate") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("InstallDate");

            var decValue = key.GetValue("EstimatedSize") == null ? "0" : key.GetValue("EstimatedSize");
            installedApp._estimatedSize = decValue.ToString() == "0" ? string.Empty : Common.GetSize(decValue.ToString());

            installedApp._systemIcon = key.GetValue("DisplayIcon") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("DisplayIcon");

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(installedApp._systemIcon) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(installedApp._displayName))
                installedApp._systemIcon = await this.GetIconForRoot(installedApp._displayName);


            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(installedApp._systemIcon))
                installedApp._systemIcon = installedApp._systemIcon.Replace("\"", string.Empty).Trim();

            installedApp._displayVersion = key.GetValue("DisplayVersion") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("DisplayVersion");
            installedApp._uninstallString = key.GetValue("UninstallString") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("UninstallString");
            installedApp._modifyPath = key.GetValue("ModifyPath") == null ? string.Empty : (string)key.GetValue("ModifyPath");

            Common.FileSize += Int32.Parse(decValue.ToString());

            return installedApp;
        }
```

Then I added the app.manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel
          level="asInvoker"
          uiAccess="false"/>
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Comment: @Gehen - Would be useful if you could point out which line of code you've changed.